# In security context, what is the difference between masquerading and spoofing?

Tags: ssl, spoofing

I'm reading a paper named "[SSL and TLS: A Beginners' Guide](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/protocols/ssl-tls-beginners-guide-1029)" and I found two new terms to me that I don't quite distinguish: **masquerading** and **spoofing**.

What I found is that both are referred to use a fake identity but I didn't find what are their differences exactly.

Can anyone tell me what they are?

Kind regards,
Andrés-J. Cremades

Answer (score 0):

Both technics are changing the adress of a communication partner, but their intention is different.

Masquerading is use, if you want to be (or your admin wants you to be) hidden behind a 'mask'. For example NAT, wenn alle adresses in a local network are 'tunneled' to the internet throu a proxy with only one internet adress. The partner on the internet can only see that public adress of the proxy and cannot say who is communicating. The proxy is handling all open connections and translating the public to the specfic lokal adress.

Therefore spoofing means, that someone is sitting inbetween your communication, like a 'man in the middel', capturing the packets and deliver changed ones. Both communication partners do not know abount him. They think, they are communicating directly with each other, but they don't. Also the packets information could be changed without notice. So, this could be used for hacking.

So mainly, it's the intention that makeds the difference.